# inject subcriber data to journey builder entry source directly from web page

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

This might seems to be an easy question but I have searched and found no solution for this query of mine.

I would like to know if it is possible to directly inject subscribers from a web page submit form which is built in java and where email and phone number are being captured, (we are not using cloud pages form)

Use that email address in journey builder to send email and SMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As API-Keys/Credentials are needed to do this, you should perform the injection from your website's backend. Depending on the programming language your website is written in, there are different libraries you can use to achieve this. However you can also do this completely on your own by just sending the correct payload to the Marketing Cloud API.

An example payload for triggering a journey builder entry event with event data can be found in the marketing cloud documentation: [POST /interaction/v1/events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm)

**The request could look something like this:**

> Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
>   POST /interaction/v1/events
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

```
{
    "ContactID": "CONTACTID_OF_SUBSCRIBER",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"EVENT_DEFINITION_KEY",
    "EstablishContactKey": true,
    "Data": {
        "email": "some@email.com",
        "phone": "555555555"
    }
}
```

**Here you can find some of the available SDKs:**

- [FuelSDK-Node-REST](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-REST)
- [FuelSDK-PHP](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP)
- [FuelSDK-Ruby](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Ruby)
- [FuelSDK-Java](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cloud Pages for your form you can choose Cloud Pages Form Submit Event as your entry source. Here's a link to the [Journey Builder Entry Source Documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/) if you're looking for additional information. [image: Cloud Pages Submit form]